# No type was found that matches the controller name when extending CustomApiController from external dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a C# solution with 2 projects:

1. library dll
2. webapp (web api)

In the first project I've extended the ApiController class to customize some behaviors, my goal is to use that dll when creating other projects to increase my productivity by simply adding a reference to it.
The code I've done is something like:

```
    public class CustomController : ApiController
    {
        //add some properties and private/protected helping methods

        public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
             //customize some initialization before processing request.
        }
    }
```

Second project is a dummy project to test if first one works, I've added a reference for the first project (dll library)

```
public class EmptyController : CustomController 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Home()
    {
        return "whatever.";
    }
}
```

And the config file:

```
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now, when I run the second project, it starts up, but when I try to access the controller (/api/Empty/Home) I get a message

> "No type was found that matches the controller name Empty"

I tried copying the CustomController class from the first project to web project, it worked perfectly. But when I moved it back to the dll project, got the same error again.

I've tried changing the IAssembliesResolver service in the config file, the thing is that the dll is already loaded, no idea why it's not seeing the controller though.
Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Comment: @IlyaChumakov don't think it's a duplicate, that question is for MVC with .Net Core, while mine is about WebApi with old .net framework (not core), also that question is about accessing a route in the external class, in my case the external class contains no routes, but the classes that inherit it aren't assigned to routes.

Comment: my fault, sorry.

Comment: FYI: I can't reproduce this error. Inheriting a controller from another dll is working just fine with the latest `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3`. It could be helpful to create two clean projects and test it to ensure the error repeats at your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seem to happen because of different package version in the dll and webapp projects, the webapp used an older version due to the template, while the dll downloaded the latest version. After updating both projects to use the same version it works without problems.